# PDF Thumbnail display

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, thumbnails

How to display PDF thumbnails in ASP page

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality for ASP to process and manipulate PDF files.  You will need to install a custom component on your server, make sure your webhost allows this, or ask them for a list of installed objects as they often have ones that will do what you want.

A good free on is GFlax:
http://download.cnet.com/GFLAx/3000-10248_4-10327603.html

It will allow you to chop a PDF up into seperate JPEG files, and from there you can get the object to resize the JPEGs into different thumbnail sizes for your needs.

The GFlax documentation should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this? [Mapsoft ThumbNails](http://www.mapsoft.com/thumbnails.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [Ghost script sharp](https://github.com/mephraim/ghostscriptsharp)  for displaying  pdf thumbnail . Here is the code

```
GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb(filepath, thumbnailPath, 1, 20, 20);
```